# null to listOf(), not null to listOf(value) in Kotlin in one liner?

Tags: kotlin, null, option-type, kotlin-null-safety

Let `f()` return a nullable value.

What I want to do is that
if `f()` is null, get an empty list,
else if `f()` is not null, get a list of the single item `value`.

In Scala, we can do something like this:

```
Option(f()).toList
```

or more verbosely

```
Option(f()).map(v => List(v)).getOrElse(List.empty)
```

In Kotlin, there is no `Option` (assuming no Funktionale library), and null does not have `toList()` unlike (`None: Option`) in Scala.

We have the Elvis operator, but null will be inside the `listOf()` function, so it will be

```
listOf(f() ?: /* What can I do here? */)
```

What we want for null is `listOf(/*no argument */)`, but the Elvis operator requires an argument, so `listOf(f() ?: )` will result in a compile error.

At least we can do

```
val v = f()
if (v == null) listOf() else listOf(v)
```

but it is a two liner.

Is there some expression for this?

Where I will use this expression is in the class's primary constructor default argument, so if it is not a one liner, it will be enclosed in brackets, so something like this:

```
class A(
    val p1: List<V> = run {
        val v = f()
        if (v == null) listOf() else listOf(v)
    },
    val p2: ... = ...,
    ...)
```

This looks pretty ugly, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*EDIT*

As @Naetmul pointed out, `listOfNotNull(f())` is syntactically better to what I originally posted below, and also takes a variable number of arguments, for example

```
val myList = listOfNotNull(f(), g(), h())
```

will return a list of all the results that were not null.

---

<strike>I would use `let` here.</strike>

```
val myList = f()?.let { listOf(it) } ?: emptyList()
```

Use a [`?.` safe call](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) on the return value of `f()`, then use `let` to run a code block. If `f()` is null, it won't run this block of code, resulting in a null value. Then we use the [`?:` elvis operator](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) to fall back to an empty list.

Here it is broken up into several lines for a better understanding

```
val myValue = f()
val myList: List<Any>
if (myValue != null) {
    myList = listOf(myValue)
} else {
    myList = emptyList()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this specific question, I can do

```
listOfNotNull(f())
```